# Powershell: Comparing 2 CSVs and adding from 1 to the other, without duplicating

Tags: powershell, csv, duplicates, copy, compare

I had a question about copying from one CSV to another, without creating duplicates. I figured it out. See the accepted answer below.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try that script? Did you get any error or unwanted result?
Maybe you could achieve something with the nested foreach, but it is hard to help when I don't know what did you try.
http://www.vladsitblog.com/compare-two-csv-files-via-powershell/

Comment: @manu clearly not enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with (adds unique from update to master, then checks master for duplicates):

```
$updatefile = 'C:\path\to\file\update.csv'
$masterlist = 'C:\path\to\file\masterlist.csv'


get-content $updatefile | Select -Unique | add-content $masterlist 

(Get-Content $masterlist | Group-Object | %{$_.group | select -First 1}) | Out-File $masterlist -encoding ASCII
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet, the answer is pretty easy:

```
@(get-content .\masterlist.csv) + @(get-content .\update.csv) | Select -Unique | Out-File .\masterlist.csv
```

Comment: hey thanks.. I put together something similar, but I have never used that format with `@+@`, can you explain it a little? clearly I'm not a CS major (and my other posts show I don't just ask for scripts) so I was surprised to get such a backlash for such a simple request. If I was getting paid to write scripts like this... O_o

Comment: just `(get-content .\masterlist.csv) + (get-content .\update.csv)` will probably also work but just to be sure if there is only one value in either `.cvs` file, it is converted to an array, you force it to an array by using `@()`. The plus (`+`) appends the two arrays and `Select -Unique` removes the double entries.